# Structure constants and matrix representations

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have a doubt about the relation between the structure constants of a Lie group and the representation of its algebra. Let's see an example:

For $SU(3)$ the number of generators is 8 and we write them as $\{T_a, a = 1, ..., 8\}$. Then, the adjoint (matrix) representation of these elements is

$$T_a \rightarrow [t_a^{Adj}]_{ij} = f_{aji}, \quad [T_a, T_b] = f_{abc}T_c \quad (1)$$

(We suppose implicit the sum over $c$)

From Eq. (1) and the fact of having 8 generators (so $i, j$ stand for 1 to 8), each $t_a^{Adj}$ is a 8x8 matrix, but we are used to the Gell-Mann 3x3, not 8x8, matrices as the generators' representation.

Therefore, what is happening here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You picked another representation so you got different matrices (you picked adjoint instead of natural).

Comment: Can I move from adjoint to natural representation? Or how can I construct the natural one?

Comment: The natural representation is the one coming from the Lie algebra (or Lie group) being given as a set of matrices in the first place). There is not really any reason you should be able to move from one to the other, since they are simply different (irreducible) representations.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your answer